# Connect to a sails.js instance via websockets

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Is it possible to connect any external application to my sails.js application via WebSockets?

I can use the underlying socket.io embedded in sails.js to talk between the client and server, that's not a problem.

But, I would like to connect another, separate, application to the sails.js server via websockets, and have those two communicate with each other that way, and I am wondering if this is possible?

If so, how can we do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [SailsJS documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets), we have access to the `io` object of socket.io, via `sails.io`.

From that, I just adjusted boostrap.js:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

    sails.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('helloFromClient', function (data) {
            console.log('helloFromClient', data);
            socket.emit('helloFromServer', {server: 'says hello'});
        });
    });

    cb();
};
```

Then, in my other nodejs application, *which could also be another SailsJS application and I will test that later on*, I simply connected and sent a message:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.emit('helloFromClient', {client: 'says hello'});
socket.on('helloFromServer', function (data) {
    console.log('helloFromServer', data);
});
```

And here are the outputs.

In SailsJS I see:

```
helloFromClient { client: 'says hello' }
```

In my client nodejs app I see:

```
helloFromServer { server: 'says hello' }
```

So, it seems to be working just fine.